# How to sum within a groupby over with both numeric and non-numeric data types

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Consider the following `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['X', 'a', 0, 1],
        ['X', 'b', 2, 3],
        ['X', 'c', 4, 5],
        ['Y', 'a', 6, 7],
        ['Y', 'b', 8, 9],
        ['Y', 'c', 10, 11],
    ], columns=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'])
df
```

[image]

```
df.dtypes

One      object
Two      object
Three     int64
Four      int64
dtype: object
```

When I `df.sum()` I get what `sum` would do over the each of the columns.

```
df.sum()

One      XXXYYY
Two      abcabc
Three        30
Four         36
dtype: object
```

However, I'd like to perform this within a `groupby`.  I'd expect this to work

```
df.groupby('One').sum()
```

[image]

But it appears to only sum over numeric columns.  What is a convenient way to perform the same summation as `df.sum()`?

I'd expect this result

```
pd.concat([df.set_index('One').loc[i].sum() for i in ['X', 'Y']],
          axis=1, keys=['X', 'Y']).T.rename_axis('One')
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, I upvote it. ';)

Comment: and question too ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to achieve your desired result by using `agg` with a `lambda`:

```
In [6]:
df.groupby('One').agg(lambda x: x.sum())

Out[6]:
     Two  Three  Four
One                  
X    abc      6     9
Y    abc     24    27
```